# Composite Relationship assign parent reference to child / Deserialization

Tags: java, json, oop, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a class like:

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class Parent {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;

    @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Child child;

    public Parent() {
        this.child = new Child();
        child.setParent(this);
    }
}
```

And a Child in a composite relation like:

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class Child {
    private String nameChild;
    private String lastNameChild;

    @JsonManagedReference
    private Parent parent;
}
```

What I want:

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Example {
    @Test
    public void Test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setAddress("Address");
        parent.setLastName("LastName");
        parent.setName("Name");

        parent.getChild().setNameChild("ChildName");
        parent.getChild().setLastNameChild("ChildLastName");

        Parent referenceToParent = parent.getChild().getParent();

        ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = objMapper.writeValueAsString(referenceToParent);

        Parent m = objMapper.readValue(json, Parent.class);
    }
}
```

I want to get in referenceToParent the reference to the parent from the child in a composite relationship.

1. How can I structure my object?
2. How can I handle Child -> Parent field for deserialization?

The result of deserialization Notice Child elements nonexistent, which is not the expected behavior:

```
{"name":"Name","lastName":"LastName","address":"Address"}
```

Comment: In your `Parent`'s `Child` setter, have `Parent` set the `Child`'s parent to itself.

Comment: Thanks, Johnathan, may you please write a piece of code, I would appreciate it.

Comment: C# or Java? You have added both tags.

Comment: c# or Java, no problem. I do not want to create the child object manually from my test, for example in the case of deserialization the composite relation parent child should happen automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can override the generated Setter methods of `setChild` and `setParent` like the follow

```java
// Parent class
public void setChild(Child child) {
  this.child = child;
    if (child.getParent() == null) { // Prevent StackOverflowException
      child.setParent(this);
    }
}
//Child class
public void setParent(Parent parent) {
  this.parent = parent;
  if (parent.getChild() == null) { // Prevent StackOverflowException
    parent.setChild(this);
  }
}

@Test
public void test() {
  Parent parent = new Parent();
  parent.setAddress("Address");
  parent.setLastName("LastName");
  parent.setName("Name");

  Child child = new Child();
  child.setNameChild("ChildName");
  child.setLastNameChild("ChildLastName");

  parent.setChild(child);

  assertNotNull(parent.getChild().getParent());
}
```

The problem with your call `parent.getChild().setLastNameChild("ChildLastName");` is that there is no child at this time. Therefore, either create a always a `Child` in the contructor in `Parent` or pass the `Child` object like i did.

--- Edit

If I understand you comment right, the you can to the following as an alternative to prevent manually instanication.

```java
@Setter
@Getter
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;

    @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    private Child child;

    public Parent() {
        this.child = new Child();
        child.setParent(this);
    }
}
```

```java
@Test
    public void test() {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setAddress("Address");
        parent.setLastName("LastName");
        parent.setName("Name");

        parent.getChild().setNameChild("ChildName");
        parent.getChild().setLastNameChild("ChildLastName");

        assertNotNull(parent.getChild().getParent());
    }
```

The private `setChild()` method prevent overriding the child. If you want to want to set the child manually as well than you have to combine both approaches.

The public `setParent()` may be critical because one can override the related parent.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help, It would exist the possibility to do the assignation automatically? I mean for example in the case of Deserialization the relation should be created automatically.

Comment: The problem happens at deserialization. If you serialize the object as is it will create a stack overflow. The parent field in Child class will reference to parent as we said. I need to Deserialize and have Parent field populated in Child as well automatically

Comment: Then you may edit your initial question because I don't know what you mean by deserialization because it is not mentioned in your question.

Comment: Let the classes implement the interface `java.io.Serializable`.

Comment: Caused by your edit that you actually use JSON with Jackson the content totally changes. The next time you asked a question, please provide all necessary details. In this case I would suggest asking a new question with all provided details.